# Finding the probability that $P \{W(2)> |W(1)|\}$, where $W(t)$ is the standard Wiener process. Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

I know that the increments of the Brownian motion are independent, and it looks like that might be of use in calculating this probability.

I thought that this might be the case:

$$P\{W(2)> |W(1)|\}= P\{W(2)>W(1);W(2)>-W(1) \} = \\ P\{W(2)-W(1)>0 , W(2)+W(1)>0\}$$

$$W(2)-W(1): N(0,1) -\text{normal distribution parameters 0,1}$$ 
$$W(2)+W(1): N(0,3) -\text{normal distribution parameters 0,3}$$

Then I have two independent variables, allowing me to multiply the density functions and integrating over the first quadrant with limits $0, +\infty$

Comment: The event you want can be written as the disjoint union of the events $\{W(1)>0\}\cap\{W(2)-W(1)>0\}$ and $\{W(1)<0\}\cap\{W(2)+W(1)>0\}$. This should show you no integration is necessary

Comment: Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=W(2)-W(1)$ and $Y=W(2)+W(1)$. We can see that the vector $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian hence its density can be computed. However, it seems that $X$ and $Y$ are correlated hence the expression of the density is unfortunately not the product of densities.